# Change color space of exisiting BufferedImage?

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, color-space

Is it possible to change the color space of an existing BufferedImage object **without copying all pixels to a new BufferedImage object**? I couldn't find a method for that, but maybe I just didn't find it? I would like to change the color space from BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR to BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY.

Comment: *"without copying all pixels to a new BufferedImage object?"*  Why?

Comment: Because it is more elegant than creating a temporary object for that, copy all pixels using a for loop and assign the temporary object to the original BufferdImage.

Answer (score 2):

No.

From [the Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

**TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR**
Represents an image with 8-bit RGBA color components with the colors Blue, Green, and Red stored in 3 bytes and 1 byte of alpha.

**TYPE_BYTE_BINARY**
Represents an opaque byte-packed 1, 2, or 4 bit image.

The size of the pixels are different - 4B vs 1B.
Even if it is possible to modify the image's metadata in the Java structure object, since the pixel size is different this shouldn't work in place(*).

(*) The new buffer is smaller, so theoretically it should be possible to reuse the memory by creating a new image that contains the same buffer (however not fully used).
You will still need to write your own loop which iterates the pixels **in the order of placement in the buffer**, modifies their color space (ARGB->Intensity), and writes them into the place that source pixel /4 was in.
Try to use this constructor to reuse the buffer: `BufferedImage(ColorModel cm, WritableRaster raster, boolean isRasterPremultiplied, Hashtable properties)`